# Flattening Amazon Response XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis, amazon-mws

I am trying to use XSLT to flatten or normalize an XML response that I am getting from Amazon MWS. My plan is to pre-process the XML response with the XSLT in SSIS before importing the data into SQL Server in a relational format.

Anyway, I am pretty close, but I am having an issue that I can't seem to resolve. When I use the XSLT to transform the XML, I am getting the values out, but no XML elements. I need a valid XML file when I am done, so this is a problem...

Here is what I have so far...

XML Response

```
            <ListFinancialEventsResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/Finances/2015-05-01">
            <ListFinancialEventsResult>
            <NextToken>2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhcEXAMPLE</NextToken>
            <FinancialEvents>
            <ProductAdsPaymentEventList/>
            <RentalTransactionEventList/>
            <PayWithAmazonEventList/>
            <ServiceFeeEventList>
            <ServiceFeeEvent>
            <FeeDescription>Love Tree Women's Linen Wide Leg Trouser Pant, Dark Coral, Medium</FeeDescription>
            <SellerSKU>L8399P_DCRL-2</SellerSKU>
            </ServiceFeeEvent>
            <ServiceFeeEvent>
            <FeeDescription>Love Tree Women's Linen Wide Leg Trouser Pant, Dark Coral, Medium</FeeDescription>
            <SellerSKU>L8399P_DCRL-2</SellerSKU>
            <FeeList>
            <FeeComponent>
            <FeeType>FBACustomerReturnPerOrderFee</FeeType>
            <FeeAmount>
            <CurrencyAmount>-1.0</CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            </FeeAmount>
            </FeeComponent>
            <FeeComponent>
            <FeeType>FBACustomerReturnPerUnitFee</FeeType>
            <FeeAmount>
            <CurrencyAmount>-1.46</CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            </FeeAmount>
            </FeeComponent>
            <FeeComponent>
            <FeeType>FBACustomerReturnWeightBasedFee</FeeType>
            <FeeAmount>
            <CurrencyAmount>-0.96</CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            </FeeAmount>
            </FeeComponent>
            </FeeList>
            </ServiceFeeEvent>
            </ServiceFeeEventList>
            </FinancialEvents>
            </ListFinancialEventsResult>
            <ResponseMetadata>
            <RequestId>612b2053-9e1f-469c-82a0-af9b19c671fa</RequestId>
            </ResponseMetadata>
            </ListFinancialEventsResponse>
```

XSL Template

```
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
            <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:template match="/ListFinancialEventsResponse">
            <ListFinancialEventsResponse>
            <ListFinancialEventsResult>
            <NextToken></NextToken>
            <FinancialEvents>
            <ProductAdsPaymentEventList></ProductAdsPaymentEventList>
            <RentalTransactionEventList></RentalTransactionEventList>
            <PayWithAmazonEventList></PayWithAmazonEventList>
            <ServiceFeeEventList>
            <xsl:for-each select="ServiceFeeEventList/ServiceFeeEvent">
            <ServiceFeeEvent>
            <FeeDescription><xsl:value-of select="FeeDescription"/></FeeDescription>
            <SellerSKU><xsl:value-of select="SellerSKU"/></SellerSKU>
            <FeeType><xsl:value-of select="FeeList/FeeComponent/FeeType"/></FeeType>
            <CurrencyAmount><xsl:value-of select="FeeList/FeeComponent/FeeAmount/CurrencyAmount"/></CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode><xsl:value-of select="FeeList/FeeComponent/FeeAmount/CurrencyCode"/></CurrencyCode>
            </ServiceFeeEvent>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </ServiceFeeEventList>
            </FinancialEvents>
            </ListFinancialEventsResult>
            <ResponseMetadata>
            <RequestId></RequestId>
            </ResponseMetadata>
            </ListFinancialEventsResponse>
            </xsl:template>       
            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

            2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhcEXAMPLE






            Love Tree Women's Linen Wide Leg Trouser Pant, Dark Coral, Medium
            L8399P_DCRL-2


            Love Tree Women's Linen Wide Leg Trouser Pant, Dark Coral, Medium
            L8399P_DCRL-2


            FBACustomerReturnPerOrderFee

            -1.0
            USD



            FBACustomerReturnPerUnitFee

            -1.46
            USD



            FBACustomerReturnWeightBasedFee

            -0.96
            USD








            612b2053-9e1f-469c-82a0-af9b19c671fa
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Please format and indent your XML and XSLT correctly.  Your problem is that the XML is in a namespace and your XSLT is matching in the default namespace, so it does not match anything in your input.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Nodes of your source-xml are in namespace `http://mws.amazonservices.com/Finances/2015-05-01`. Your xpath-statements are selecting in a default namespace. So there is a mismatch. None of your templates get executed and a in xslt build in template generates your "string" output.

(2) One solution would to map a prefix to the namespace and prefix your xpath-statements:

Add this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:f="http://mws.amazonservices.com/Finances/2015-05-01" exclude-result-prefixes="f">
```

So you have to change to e.g. [you have to do it for all! notice the `f:`]:

```
... select="f:FeeList/f:FeeComponent/f:FeeType"...
```

(3) Your `for-each` is wrong. The context node is `ListFinancialEventsResponse` (matching node of processing template). So you have to write:

```
<xsl:for-each select="f:ListFinancialEventsResult/f:FinancialEvents/f:ServiceFeeEventList/f:ServiceFeeEvent">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had seen so many answers regarding namespaces, but I just could get them to work... It was because of the 3 issue. Thanks a ton. I will post the final result when I get all the way through things. I need to fine tune the for each stuff to get everything fully flattened...

Comment: Close the answer via accepting it. [How to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is the finished product. Works great. Had to work through some nesting and such, but here it is:

XML Response:

```
            <ListFinancialEventsResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/Finances/2015-05-01">
            <ListFinancialEventsResult>
            <NextToken>2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhcEXAMPLE</NextToken>
            <FinancialEvents>
            <ProductAdsPaymentEventList/>
            <RentalTransactionEventList/>
            <PayWithAmazonEventList/>
            <ServiceFeeEventList>
            <ServiceFeeEvent>
            <FeeDescription>Love Tree Women's Linen Wide Leg Trouser Pant, Dark Coral, Medium</FeeDescription>
            <SellerSKU>L8399P_DCRL-2</SellerSKU>
            </ServiceFeeEvent>
            <ServiceFeeEvent>
            <FeeDescription>Love Tree Women's Linen Wide Leg Trouser Pant, Dark Coral, Medium</FeeDescription>
            <SellerSKU>L8399P_DCRL-2</SellerSKU>
            <FeeList>
            <FeeComponent>
            <FeeType>FBACustomerReturnPerOrderFee</FeeType>
            <FeeAmount>
            <CurrencyAmount>-1.0</CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            </FeeAmount>
            </FeeComponent>
            <FeeComponent>
            <FeeType>FBACustomerReturnPerUnitFee</FeeType>
            <FeeAmount>
            <CurrencyAmount>-1.46</CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            </FeeAmount>
            </FeeComponent>
            <FeeComponent>
            <FeeType>FBACustomerReturnWeightBasedFee</FeeType>
            <FeeAmount>
            <CurrencyAmount>-0.96</CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            </FeeAmount>
            </FeeComponent>
            </FeeList>
            </ServiceFeeEvent>
            </ServiceFeeEventList>
            </FinancialEvents>
            </ListFinancialEventsResult>
            <ResponseMetadata>
            <RequestId>612b2053-9e1f-469c-82a0-af9b19c671fa</RequestId>
            </ResponseMetadata>
            </ListFinancialEventsResponse>
```

XSLT:

```
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://mws.amazonservices.com/Finances/2015-05-01">
            <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:template match="/my:ListFinancialEventsResponse">
            <ListFinancialEventsResponse>
            <ListFinancialEventsResult>
            <NextToken><xsl:value-of select="my:ListFinancialEventsResult/my:NextToken"/></NextToken>
            <FinancialEvents>
            <ProductAdsPaymentEventList></ProductAdsPaymentEventList>
            <RentalTransactionEventList></RentalTransactionEventList>
            <PayWithAmazonEventList></PayWithAmazonEventList>
            <ServiceFeeEventList>
            <xsl:for-each select="my:ListFinancialEventsResult/my:FinancialEvents/my:ServiceFeeEventList/my:ServiceFeeEvent">
            <ServiceFeeEvent>
            <FeeDescription><xsl:value-of select="my:FeeDescription"/></FeeDescription>
            <SellerSKU><xsl:value-of select="my:SellerSKU"/></SellerSKU>
            <xsl:for-each select="my:FeeList/my:FeeComponent">
            <FeeType><xsl:value-of select="my:FeeType"/></FeeType>
            <CurrencyAmount><xsl:value-of select="my:FeeAmount/my:CurrencyAmount"/></CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode><xsl:value-of select="my:FeeAmount/my:CurrencyCode"/></CurrencyCode>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </ServiceFeeEvent>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </ServiceFeeEventList>
            </FinancialEvents>
            </ListFinancialEventsResult>
            <ResponseMetadata>
            <RequestId><xsl:value-of select="my:ResponseMetadata/my:RequestId"/></RequestId>
            </ResponseMetadata>
            </ListFinancialEventsResponse>
            </xsl:template>       
            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <ListFinancialEventsResponse xmlns:my="http://mws.amazonservices.com/Finances/2015-05-01">
            <ListFinancialEventsResult>
            <NextToken>2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhcEXAMPLE</NextToken>
            <FinancialEvents>
            <ProductAdsPaymentEventList/>
            <RentalTransactionEventList/>
            <PayWithAmazonEventList/>
            <ServiceFeeEventList>
            <ServiceFeeEvent>
            <FeeDescription>Love Tree Women's Linen Wide Leg Trouser Pant, Dark Coral, Medium</FeeDescription>
            <SellerSKU>L8399P_DCRL-2</SellerSKU>
            </ServiceFeeEvent>
            <ServiceFeeEvent>
            <FeeDescription>Love Tree Women's Linen Wide Leg Trouser Pant, Dark Coral, Medium</FeeDescription>
            <SellerSKU>L8399P_DCRL-2</SellerSKU>
            <FeeType>FBACustomerReturnPerOrderFee</FeeType>
            <CurrencyAmount>-1.0</CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <FeeType>FBACustomerReturnPerUnitFee</FeeType>
            <CurrencyAmount>-1.46</CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <FeeType>FBACustomerReturnWeightBasedFee</FeeType>
            <CurrencyAmount>-0.96</CurrencyAmount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            </ServiceFeeEvent>
            </ServiceFeeEventList>
            </FinancialEvents>
            </ListFinancialEventsResult>
            <ResponseMetadata>
            <RequestId>612b2053-9e1f-469c-82a0-af9b19c671fa</RequestId>
            </ResponseMetadata>
            </ListFinancialEventsResponse>
```

The only real thing I will need to handle is the :my at the end of the xmlns. I tried to use exclude-result-prefixes="my", but it took the whole thing out. Anyway, hope this helps someone else. Thanks for the input.

Comment: "*I tried to use exclude-result-prefixes="my", but it took the whole thing out.*" And so it should, because it is redundant. The nodes of your result are in no-namespace. If you remove only the `:my` part from the namespace declaration, it will put all the elements of your output into that namespace. And your target application will probably not like that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, the expected result could be produced with only this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://mws.amazonservices.com/Finances/2015-05-01"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- move all elements into no-namespace  -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove these wrappers  -->
<xsl:template match="my:FeeList | my:FeeComponent | my:FeeAmount">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for showing me this. I will look over this and try to implement it. This was literally the first thing I have done in XSLT, so I can use all the help I can get. Thanks again!